# Запустить SSH терминал и сразу активировать команду

Tags: bash, ssh, терминал

Через shell-команду ssh user@host я могу подключиться к терминалу удаленного сервера. А можно ли через shell-команду сразу открыть терминал удаленного сервера и автоматически ввести туда команду?

Answer (score 2):

ssh login@myip -p myport 'ls';

Comment: Спасибо! Не догадался запускать команду через порт соединения)

Comment: -p и сам порт нужно только когда не стандартный (22) порт для ssh.

Comment: @StrangeNode, ssh может список не на одну страницу полезных вещей, как то: каналы связи поверх установленного соединения, туннелирование, проксирование.